# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As the name implies. I am experiencing an issue using the reserved keyword "Module" on bower launch. It seems to relate specifically to the code below. I cannot seem to find the exact location, as it starts at "fetch-bower.js:1". Can anyone please help me to understand how to work around this problem?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

angular.module('BlurAdmin.theme.components')
.directive("digitalClock", function ($timeout, dateFilter) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, iElement) {
                (function updateClock() {
                    iElement.text(dateFilter(new Date(), 'H:mm:ss'));
                    $timeout(updateClock, 1000);
                })();
            }
        };
    });
});
```

//HTML

```
<div class="page-top clearfix" scroll-position="scrolled" max-height="50" ng-class="{'scrolled': scrolled}">
  <div class="row col-xs-12">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class="aguState col-xs-3 setText">Agu State: </div>
    <div class="aguMode col-xs-3 setText">Agu Mode: </div>
    <div class="lastUpdate col-xs-3 setText">Last Update: </div>
    <digital-clock></digital-clock>
</div>
```

//Directive.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.theme.components')
      .directive('pageTop', pageTop);

  /** @ngInject */
  function pageTop() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/theme/components/pageTop/pageTop.html'
    };
  }

})();
```

full error

```
fetch-bower.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at fetch-bower.js:1
(anonymous) @ fetch-bower.js:1
```

Comment: @Jax No good, threw a whole list of warnings, but the error still remains in the browser.

Comment: post your complete code with references

Comment: try `angular.module('BlurAdmin.theme.components', [])` as stated in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

Comment: @PatrickEvans To clarify, the browser tools are showing the issue. Pointing to Bower launch position 1

Comment: are you refering the directive in index.html

Comment: @Sajeetharan can you clarify the question? Still very new to angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you refer the angular.js and Directive.js in the index.html of the application

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="directive.js"></script>
```

also you should have empty dependencies injected to your application,

```
  angular.module('BlurAdmin.theme.components',[])
      .directive('pageTop', pageTop)
```