# Module not recognized in Javascript file within an Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

Even if there are a lot threads that talk about this particular problem, non of them solved the issue I am seeing.

I have an existing Angular 4 application in which I am loading Javascript files as follows within the index.html:

```
<script src="assets/js/libs/three.js.r86/three.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/libs/three.js.r86/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/TrackballControls.js"></script>
...
```

Some of those JS files are having the following statement:

```
module.exports = DetectionPoint;
```

When loading the application I am consistently getting the following error:

> > ReferenceError: module is not defined

Based on my reading It seems related to a very basic problem in loading commonJS(not 100% sure)

- Is there something to add in the package.json for having the CommonJS loaded?
- Is this related to the fact that i am loading those JS in the index.html?

P.S: I already went over the following threads with no luck:

- [Karma/Jasmine related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622382/referenceerror-module-is-not-defined-karma-jasmine-configuration-with-angular)
- [Load Angular.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495162/uncaught-referenceerror-module-is-not-defined) - This one is interesting but I could not load the angular.js file, not sure if I should download it first from somewhere

Thx

Comment: actually angular4 is built with typescript. so every js library you wnat to use you should declare the library object like: declare const $:any, or to install proper typing like:npm i @types/jquery

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of investigation, following are the steps required to solve this problem.

1. Download browserify
2. Run browserify on each problematic file
3. Include the resulted file in your HTML/JS file

> ```
> npm install -g browserify
> browserify  log.js > logBundle.js
> <script src="assets/js/logBundle.js"></script>
> ```